# Filtro modelo datetime Django

Tags: python, django, flask

Eu tenho um modelo que é basicamente o seguinte :

```py
class Sample(models.Model):
    date = fields.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

Agora, com isso eu quero filtrar somente o mês nesse modelo

Como eu pego somente o mês nesse modelo ?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o modulo **datetime** para fazer isso.

Use o método **.strftime()**. Veja abaixo:

```
from datetime import datetime

data_hora = datetime.now()
mes = data_hora.strftime('%m')
print(mes)
```

Ele irá retornar somente o mês do horário atual.

### Conclusão

Desta forma você transforma seu objeto **datetime** para um objeto **str**. Ele faz isso de acordo com a formatação passada como argumento para o método **.strftime()**.
Para entrar mais a fundo sobre a formatação recomendo esta [leitura](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_datetime.asp).